# How can I run github web application on localhost

Tags: github, open-source

For a project I am trying to develop a recommender for GitHub. To start with is there any way  I can run a opensource GitHub web interface on localhost but connect to the public git repositories.

```
 OR
```

I have this one which only works for local repositories.

https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitweb.html

So is there a way to crawl github repositories to create a classifier

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to run GitHub locally, as it's a closed-source commercial application*.

There are a number of open-source web-based Git interfaces, as you have already discovered. One that you didn't mention but that might be worth considering is [GitLab](https://www.gitlab.com/), which has a more GitHub-like interface than Gitweb.

If you want to interface with GitHub's repository data, your best bet will be to use [their API](http://developer.github.com/v3/). Without knowing what language you're working in it's hard to give more information than that.

If you're working in Ruby, Objective-C, .NET or Go, you should also have a look at [Octokit](http://octokit.github.io/), a set of official libraries for interacting with GitHub.

*Actually, you can run the [Enterprise version](https://enterprise.github.com/) locally, but it's fairly expensive and I get the sense that you're looking for something open and / or free.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will be using python for all back-end stuffs and the the interface above which I mentioned is in CGI.